# Is there a precise definition of "mathematical formula"?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

In the [Wikipedia article for Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula) (which has no references), it is claimed that:

"The informal use of the term formula in science refers to the general construct of a relationship between given quantities....
In mathematics, a formula is an entity constructed using the symbols and formation rules of a given logical language."

This seems to suggest that a 'formula' can be defined as a regular expression in some language which contains a single equal sign. Is this true?

Also, this article is completely unreferenced. Is there any reference giving such a precise definition of 'formula'?

Comment: it would make sense to distinguish "formula" from "equation", perhaps along the lines of this Wikipedia quote: "In a general context, formulas are applied to provide a mathematical solution for real world problems." Just today I visited an exhibit of "100 Years of Philips Research", where I read that the initial goal of this laboratory was to "derive the formula of the light bulb".

Comment: I agree; but it seems hard to find a reference that takes any position at all. If someone answers this question well, this question could be a reference.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38155

Comment: In my naive understanding, a formula is a recipe for calculation and, in that respect, a very condensed encoding of an algorithm (at least in a mathematical context).  An equation on the contrary, can either be a statement (nothing to do) or a task for which an algorithm is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every book of mathematical logic should be a good reference where to find the notion of formula.

Usually when one refers to formulas it means formulas of a first order language.
A first order language is specified by a family of symbols of three types: constants symbols, function symbols and predicate or relation symbols.
From this symbols and the variables you can build all the terms and formulas.

Basically terms are either variables, constant or sequence of the form $f(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ where $f$ is a function symbol and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are terms (this is a sort of recursive definition, one that can be codified in a formal grammar indeed).

Formulas are defined in a similar (recursive) fashion: a formula is either an equation of the form $t_1=t_2$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms, a predicate of the form $P(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ where $P$ is a predicate symbol and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are terms, or a combination obtained from this basic (atomic) formulas via connectives and quantifier application.

My apologize for the absence of details but you can really find all this stuff in every basic book on the subject.

For your question about the regularity of the grammar, at the moment I don't have any proof but my guess is that a first order language isn't a regular one. I suppose that using pumping lemma could be constructed strings that aren't first order formulas. If that would be the case then I such kind of language, the set of first order formulas of a first order language can't be regular.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So would these two be considered 'standard'? Richard Epstein "Classical Mathematical Logic" and
Wolfgang Rautenberg "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic"

Comment: I suppose, I actually never studied this stuff by any particular book but used course notes. 
I believe that all these basic definition can be easily find in course notes of a course in mathematical logic.

Comment: Since the OP seems interested in the wikipedia entry, it might be worth pointing out that this answers concerns the notion of formula as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_(mathematical_logic).